# How to operate on only one type of derived class when working with multiple derived classes?

Tags: c++

I have 1 base class, `Item`, and 3 derived classes: `CD`, `Book`, & `List`.

I figured out how to print out and add `Item` objects, regardless of whether it's a `Book` or `CD`, in a `vector` within a `List` object.  But I can't figure out how to print only `Book`s or only `CD`s. I can't make any mentions of a `CD` or `Book` class in the `List` class, and I can't move the `bool isBook` or `isCD` members to the base class.

```cpp
class Item
{
protected:
   string name; 
   int id; 

public: 
    //pure virtual methods (ex: virtual bool isID(int); 
};

class CD: public Item
{
private:
    bool isCD; 

public: 
    //defining virtual methods from base class for class specific operations
    virtual string format() { return "Artist: "  + name } 
};

class Book: public Item
{
private:
    bool isBook; 

public: 
    //defining virtual methods from base class for class specific operations
    virtual string format() { return "Author: "  + name } 
};

class List: public Item
{
private:
    vector<Item*> holdings; 

public: 
    void Add(Item &adding) {} // already figured out  

    void printAll() // print all objects in vector regardless of type Book or CD
    {
        for(auto &i: holdings)
            cout << i->format() << '\n'; 
    } 

    void printBooks(){} 
    void PrintCDs(){}
}
```

Comment: Wanting to print only books or only CDs kind of defeats the principles of polymorphism. `List` shouldn't know about books or CDs existing. It manages *items* regardless of their type. If you want, you can differentiate item types by having virtual functions like `isCD()` in `Item`, but that would be a bug, not a feature. By the way `Add(Item adding) {} // already figured out`  If that's really the signature you gave to this function, then I'm afraid you haven't really figured it out.

Comment: You could add an 'is a' enum to the base class and have the derived classes set it appropriately.  Then you can ask a derived item what it actually is and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `isCD` and `isBook` boolean members in each class.  You can use `dynamic_cast` instead, eg:

```cpp
class List: public Item
{
private:
    vector<Item*> holdings; 

public: 
    ...

    void printAll() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
            cout << i->format() << '\n'; 
    } 

    void printBooks() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
        {
            if (Book *b = dynamic_cast<Book*>(i))
                cout << b->format() << '\n'; 
        }
    } 

    void PrintCDs() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
        {
            if (CD *c = dynamic_cast<CD*>(i))
                cout << c->format() << '\n'; 
        }
    } 
};
```

If you don't want to use this approach, then you can use some additional `virtual` methods instead, eg:

```cpp
class Item
{
    ...
public: 
    ...
    virtual bool isBook() const { return false; }
    virtual bool isCD() const { return false; }
};

class CD: public Item
{
    ...
public: 
    ...
    bool isCD() const override { return true; }
};

class Book: public Item
{
    ...
public: 
    ...
    bool isBook() const override { return true; }
};

class List: public Item
{
private:
    vector<Item*> holdings; 

public: 
    ...

    void printAll() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
            cout << i->format() << '\n'; 
    } 

    void printBooks() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
        {
            if (i->isBook())
                cout << i->format() << '\n';
        }
    } 

    void PrintCDs() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
        {
            if (i->isCD())
                cout << i->format() << '\n';
        }
    } 
};
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
enum ItemType { itCD, itBook };

class Item
{
    ...
public: 
    ...
    virtual ItemType getType() const = 0;
};

class CD: public Item
{
    ...
public: 
    ...
    ItemType getType() const override { return itCD; }
};

class Book: public Item
{
    ...
public: 
    ...
    ItemType getType() const override { return itBook; }
};

class List: public Item
{
private:
    vector<Item*> holdings; 

public: 
    ...

    void printAll() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
            cout << i->format() << '\n'; 
    } 

    void printBooks() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
        {
            if (i->getType() == itBook)
                cout << i->format() << '\n';
        }
    } 

    void PrintCDs() const
    {
        for(auto *i: holdings)
        {
            if (i->getType() == itCD)
                cout << i->format() << '\n';
        }
    } 
};
```